# Unsupported method: AndroidProject.getVariantNames() in Android Studio 3.4

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I just updated to **Android Studio 3.4 (Canary 5)**. Then I opened my existing project (which worked perfectly on Android Studio 3.3 Beta) and received this error:

```
ERROR: Unsupported method: AndroidProject.getVariantNames().
The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model.
```

Full clean & rebuild, Invalidate cache & restart, re-import project does not work.

**gradle-wrapper.properties**:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

**build.gradle** (project level):

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
}
```

About Android Studio

```
Android Studio 3.4 Canary 5
Build #AI-183.4284.36.34.5141831, built on November 20, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.15.0-39-generic
```

How to solve this?

Comment: How about updating `distributionUrl` to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip` ?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Finally I found out how to make things work again.

Try change to use `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip` in **gradle-wrapper.properties**

And `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'` in **build.gradle** (project level).

Comment: seem to be an issue with the new version of Android Studio

Comment: @SeanDp32 sure, hope Google will fix it soon

Comment: Same here! I tied the solution in this post an my project worked fine. I don't know why. but if anyone have this problem this is the solution

Comment: @SeanDp32 I think because the new Android Studio required newer Gradle build tools to work, but the way Google force us to upgrade it is not good.

Comment: Oh I see I been receiving messages telling me to upgrade gradle and I kept putting it off. That make sense now.

Answer (score 83):

You need to disable this setting in Android Studio:

`File` > `Settings`(or `Preferences` for previous versions) > `Experimental` > `Only sync active variant`

Comment: As soon as I checked off that flag, the theme changed to "Darkula". Weirdness.

Answer (score 6):

This problem arose after installing new Android Studio 3.3.

I installed Android 8.1 (Oreo) from `Tools -> SDK Manager` or `File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behaviour -> System Settings -> Android SDK` and the project successfully sync and build.

Answer (score 5):

Got the same error message after upgrading to Android Studio 3.3 and reloading an older project which was using an earlier version of Gradle. I fixed my project by changing the following line in the existing project level **gradle.build** file

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    }
```

In addition I had also removed some older SDKs and needed to set a Project level SDK in 'Open Module Settings'.

After these two changes the messages changed and included some auto fix links which got my project back up and running as usual.

> ERROR: Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.10.1. Current version is
> 4.4.
>
> Please fix the project's Gradle settings.
>
> *Fix Gradle wrapper and re-import project Gradle settings*

Comment: I've literally spent an hour debugging a Gradle sync failure, your answer fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Any of other responses solved the problem in my case,
I've found that it was because licenses agreement missing.

To fix you need to execute

on linux and osx:

```
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
```

or Windows:

```
> C:\Users\erik\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat --licenses
```

and accept all licences agreements.

Answer (score 1):

It happens when you installed new version of Android Studio say "3.x.x".
You can resolve this error by just adding below line in your build.gradle file.

dependencies{classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'}

Answer (score 1):

There are two different things-- distributionUrl and plugin version.

Plugin version is mentioned in Project level build.gradle file  as classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1' or 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'.

And distributionUrl refers to GradleWrapper which is in (gradle-wrapper.properties)

If you go to this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-gradle) you will see the link between the two.

Like as of April 2019 the latest plugin version is 3.4.0
and the latest distributionUrl is 5.1.1

So in your project level build.gradle file

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

and in gradle-wrapper.properties do:-

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

Then do a sync and should be good.

Answer (score 1):

Just go through this [Android Gradle plugin release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin) and you will be able to match available gradle plugin version with gradle version. The updated version of this table can be found on this site.

[image]

In the gradle-wrapper.properties file changed ths required gradle version like this

```
distributionUrl = https:\//services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

In the build.gradle file add correct gradle plugin version like this

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
}
```