# ERROR: Unsupported method: AndroidProject.getVariantNames()

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I created app on an older version of Android Studio and when I open this app in latest version (3.1.3) app is not working I am seeing an error.

```
ERROR: Unsupported method: AndroidProject.getVariantNames().
The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model.
```

Comment: > To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53498161/unsupported-method-androidproject-getvariantnames-in-android-studio-3-4

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problema yesterday and I replaced the `gradle-wrapper.properties` and change this :

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

Also had to change the `build.gradle` to :

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
}
```

Perhaps you may change this too

```
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
```

Hope you can solve with those steps.

Comment: Where i need to change  "gradle-wrapper.properties" ?

Comment: There's a file in your project structure or press three times <kbd>Shift</kbd> and then type `gradle-wrapper.properties`

Comment: and buildToolsVersion  ?

Comment: @HanumanPrasad did you solved the problem? Or shall I edit my answer?