# pip3, python does nothing on Windows cmd

Tags: python, cmd, pyinstaller

Yes, I already read [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53498161/unsupported-method-androidproject-getvariantnames-in-android-studio-3-4) question but it didn't help me.

```
C:\Users\*\Documents\git-workspace\redditCountdownGui>"C:\Program Files\WPy64-3741\python-3.7.4.amd64\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe"

C:\Users\*\Documents\git-workspace\redditCountdownGui>
```

I tried using this method:

```
C:\Users\*\Documents\git-workspace\redditCountdownGui>"C:\Program Files\WPy64-3741\python-3.7.4.amd64\python.exe" -m pyinstaller
C:\Program Files\WPy64-3741\python-3.7.4.amd64\python.exe: No module named pyinstaller

C:\Users\*\Documents\git-workspace\redditCountdownGui>
```

I can't get it to work. It's also not working for pip:

```
C:\Users\*\Documents\git-workspace\redditCountdownGui>"C:\Program Files\WPy64-3741\python-3.7.4.amd64\Scripts\pip.exe"

C:\Users\*\Documents\git-workspace\redditCountdownGui>"C:\Program Files\WPy64-3741\python-3.7.4.amd64\Scripts\pip3.exe"

C:\Users\*\Documents\git-workspace\redditCountdownGui>
```

I also tried adding to PATH but then it's the same - no output at all.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: There is a good walkthrough here: https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/using-pip-on-windows/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using WinPython, you need to start `WinPython Command Prompt` to get all Paths set correctly. Within that shell, you can use pip as usual:

```
D:\WPy64-3740\scripts>python
Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'D:\\WPy64-3740\\python-3.7.4.amd64\\python.exe'
>>> exit()

D:\WPy64-3740\scripts>python -m pip install requests
Requirement already satisfied: requests in d:\wpy64-3740\python-3.7.4.amd64\lib\site-packages (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in d:\wpy64-3740\python-3.7.4.amd64\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2019.6.16)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in d:\wpy64-3740\python-3.7.4.amd64\lib\site-packages (from requests) (1.25.3)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet in d:\wpy64-3740\python-3.7.4.amd64\lib\site-packages (from requests) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna in d:\wpy64-3740\python-3.7.4.amd64\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2.8)

D:\WPy64-3740\scripts>
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the command prompt and it found pyinstaller. I then moved the WinPython directory away from C:\Program Files which caused an permission problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a lazy answer, but this is Windoze. You should simply uninstall and reinstall Python.

During the install, the python executable *should* get added to the paths correctly ...although (depending on installer) you *may* need to specifically select a checkbox to add it to the system paths. It should also install `pip`, although (again) you may need to specifically select that in a checkbox during install.

After (proper) installation, you should be able to open a `cmd` window, and simply type `python` and be dropped into the Python working environment. You should also be able to just type `pip` and find the working copy of pip.

If you can't do this, your Windows environment has gotten screwed up :/

Please note, if you have more than one version of Python installed, you may need to type `python3` / `pip3` to access the correct version.

[image]

**The error message** `No module named pyinstaller` is because the Python can't find your `site-packages`. This is also a result of your paths being screwed up when you're calling python.

Try running the command `python -m site` to see where your `site-packages` is installed, ensure it is in your paths, and ensure that the module in question is installed there.

Different versions of Python have their ***own paths*** for site-packages. So installing a module for Python 2.7 does ***not*** install it for Python 3.x

Comment: Thank you, I installed a new Python package, I can access pyinstaller from the console now, but it stops building my file: `win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (1920, 'LoadLibraryExW', 'System can not access the file')` I tried executing admin but that doesn't change anything. I also created a venv with PyCharm but I don't know how to run pyinstaller from there..

Comment: Did you see the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57180580/pyinstaller-win32ctypes-pywin32-pywintypes-error-1920-loadlibraryexw-syst)? Unfortunately, I don't work with Pycharm much...

Comment: Yes, bu I don't know how to executa pyinstaller from a venv.

Comment: I don't usually run on Windows. But, in order to run anything from within a venv, you need to enter that venv environment. On windows, to run from within the venv in a command windows (cmd), you use `C:\Users\'Username'\venv\Scripts\activate.bat` (from [here](https://programwithus.com/learn-to-code/Pip-and-virtualenv-on-Windows/))...then run your python commands. This loads the venv environment. You can also (I assume) set the Pycharm environment to load and use the venv...although I don't know how. I use Eclipse and Atom :D